# Writing Unit Test for A Getter function in Angular v15

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ts-jest

I'm stuck in finding way to get this getter to be unit tested.

unit test snippet

```
let dataService: DataService;
let firestoreSpy: jest.Mock<Firestore>;

beforeEach(() => {
  const spy = jest.fn(() => ({
    valueChange: jest.fn(),
  })) as unknown as jest.Mocked<Firestore>;

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [DataService, { provide: Firestore, useValue: spy }],
  });

  dataService = TestBed.inject(DataService);
  firestoreSpy = TestBed.inject(Firestore) as any;
});


describe('collection get()', () => {
  it('should return a Firestore collection with the correct name', () => {
    const year = 2023;
    const collectionSpy = jest.fn(() => ({
      valueChanges: jest.fn(),
    }));

    expect(dataService.collection).toEqual(collectionSpy());
   });
});
```

Here is the service I am testing that is relevant

```
export class DataService {
  private _fireStore: Firestore = inject(Firestore);
  year: number = 2023;

  get collection() {
    return collection(this._fireStore, this.year.toString());
  }
```

When I ran this I get this jest error:

```
Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using
    provideFirebaseApp) or you're calling an AngularFire method outside of an NgModule (which is not supported).

      17 |
      18 |   get collection() {
    > 19 |     return collection(this._fireStore, this.year.toString());
         |                      ^
```

I can't seem to mock the `this_firestore` and I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite certain that only the firestore injection is missing:

```
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
        DataService, { provide: Firestore, useValue: spy },
        provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()) // this guy
    ],
});
```

Comment: outside the providers?

Comment: Nope, inside. I just updated the code. Sorry!

Comment: I'm getting an failed test.

nvalid provider for the NgModule 'DynamicTestModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [..., ..., ..., ..., ?[object Object]?]